# homogenous linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I have an equation that I can't solve. I think it's homogenous.

$$ y' =\frac{y^2 + x \sqrt{4x^2 + y^2}}{xy} $$

Comment: The second one can be also solved as an easy first order linear DE , manipulating it to this for $\frac{dx}{dy}-x=y$.   Also in the first question did you mean $y'= \frac{y^2 + x \sqrt{4x^2 + y^2}}{xy} $

Comment: The first is not an equation, and neither one is linear

Comment: Hi Hax and welcome to Math.SE. It is here mandatory to show some effort. What are your thoughts? You think the differential equation is homogeneous. Did you check it? Also, it could be good to tell the source of problems, since it might give the people answering an idea on what level to put the answer on, and what tools to use.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think, it is homogeneous?
For the homogeneous differential equations, you should use the change of variation $ y=zx.$
By this, you will have 
$$ (zxdz+z^{2}dx)-(z^{2}+\sqrt{4+z^{2}})dx=0 .$$
As you you see that it is completely easy. I'm sure with some effort you will solve lots of problems. I am a new user like you!

Comment: Assume $y=f(x)$ is an answer to this equation so for that $y$, the pair $(y,x)$ is satisfying the equation. Now give the pair $(\lambda y,\lambda x)$ to the equation, this new pair also satisfy the equation so it is indeed homogeneous.

Comment: @AmirHoseinSadeghiManesh Yes it was the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes..its homogenious..

$$ y' =\frac{y^2 + x \sqrt{4x^2 + y^2}}{xy} $$

For this, their is well known method, running by substituting, 
$$y=vx\implies y'=v+xv'$$

So, it will became as,

\begin{align}
v+xv' &=\frac{v^2x^2 + x \sqrt{4x^2 + v^2x^2}}{xvx}\\
      &=\frac{v^2 +  \sqrt{4 + v^2}}{v}
\end{align}

Now, we can write as,
$$x v'=\frac{v^2 +  \sqrt{4 + v^2}}{v}-v$$
which gives us,
$$x v'=\frac{  \sqrt{4 + v^2}}{v}$$

So,
$$ \frac v{   \sqrt{4 + v^2}}dv=\frac 1 x dx$$

Can you complete this??

Comment: @hax. If you are finding this answer helps you..you can consider to upvote and dont forget to accept it(right below the upvote button)